# Unable to encrypt Data

Tags: python, json, encryption

I am trying to encrypt user-entered information before saving it in a JSON file in a dictionary format. I am then, later in the code trying to search the JSON file for a key as specified by the user, and to de-encrypt and show the value. I have created 2 functions to do it.

The first:

```
#function to encrypt user-entered password before dumping it into a JSON file
def encryptAndDump(username, password):
    e_password = password.encode('utf-8')
    encrypted = k.encrypt(e_password)
    b64_encrypted = base64.b64encode(encrypted).decode('utf-8')
    a = {site: [username, b64_encrypted]}
    with open(dictionary, 'r') as f:
        password_dictionary = json.load(f) 
    password_dictionary = {}
    password_dictionary.update(a)
    with open(dictionary, 'w') as f:
        json.dump(password_dictionary, f)
```

In the encryptAndDump function - the variables defined outside of the function ('username' and 'password') are user input variables.

The second:

```
#function to search JSON file and decrypt password information
def searchAndDecrypt():
    r_site = input("Enter the Site Name to retrieve your credentials (Password Manager is case sensitive.): ")
    with open(dictionary, 'r') as f:
        password_dictionary = json.load(f) if f.readable() else {}
    for site, user_pass in password_dictionary.items():
        if site == r_site:
            print("ACCOUNT FOUND") 
            while True:
                c_password = pwinput.pwinput("Confirm your Password Manager password to decrypt login credentials: ")
                if c_password == m_password:
                    b64_encrypted_password = user_pass[1]
                    encrypted_password = base64.b64decode(b64_encrypted_password)
                    decrypt_user_pass = k.decrypt(encrypted_password).decode('utf-8')
                    print(decrypt_user_pass)
                    break
                else:
                    print("Invalid password.")
            break
    else:
        print("Site Account not found.")
```

For the function searchAndDecrypt the variables defined outside of the function are (site - user input and saved in JSON file) (m_password = "Str@wb3rry!")

I did initially have an error message built into the code stating when data could not be encrypted, however on the advice of some people on here I have removed it to see what the error codes coming up are. It is only coming up in response to me running the second function.

```
File "/Users/makaylagalbraith/Documents/Python/PasswordManager.py", line 157, in <module>
    searchAndDecrypt()
  File "/Users/makaylagalbraith/Documents/Python/PasswordManager.py", line 91, in searchAndDecrypt
    decrypt_user_pass = k.decrypt(encrypted_password).decode('utf-8')
  File "/Users/makaylagalbraith/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/cryptography/fernet.py", line 90, in decrypt
    return self._decrypt_data(data, timestamp, time_info)
  File "/Users/makaylagalbraith/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/cryptography/fernet.py", line 151, in _decrypt_data
    self._verify_signature(data)
  File "/Users/makaylagalbraith/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/cryptography/fernet.py", line 135, in _verify_signature
    raise InvalidToken
cryptography.fernet.InvalidToken
```

My cypher is saved earlier in the code like this

This is how I have created my cipher/key

```
key = Fernet.generate_key()
with open("key.key", "wb") as key_file:
    key_file.write(key)
k=Fernet(key)
```

Could it be something about how I have generated it/saved it?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: The code you provided uses a lot of variables that aren't scoped locally to the functions. It would help if you could clear that up to make it easier to test

Comment: I have just edited my question to clear up what they are. The vast majority of them are user input variables.

Answer (score 0):

I ran your code stripping out some of the stuff that I didn't need to make it run and it worked fine for me. Maybe you're not passing the cipher properly or it is changing before it can decrypt?

```py
from cryptography.fernet import Fernet
import base64
import json

key = Fernet.generate_key()
cipher = Fernet(key)

#function to encrypt user entered password before dumping it into a JSON file
def encryptAndDump(username, password, k, dictionary):
    e_password = password.encode('utf-8')
    encrypted = k.encrypt(e_password)
    b64_encrypted = base64.b64encode(encrypted).decode('utf-8')
    a = {'site': [username, b64_encrypted]}
    try:
        with open(dictionary, 'r') as f:
            password_dictionary = json.load(f) 
    except FileNotFoundError:
        password_dictionary = {}
    password_dictionary.update(a)
    with open(dictionary, 'w') as f:
        json.dump(password_dictionary, f)

encryptAndDump('foo', 'bar', cipher, './test.json')

#function to search JSON file and decrypt password information
def searchAndDecrypt(dictionary, k):
    #r_site = input("Enter the Site Name to retrieve your credentials (Password Manager is case sensitive.): ")
    with open(dictionary, 'r') as f:
        password_dictionary = json.load(f) if f.readable() else {}
    for site, user_pass in password_dictionary.items():
        if site == 'site': #r_site:
            print("ACCOUNT FOUND") 
            while True:
                c_password = k #pwinput.pwinput("Confirm your Password Manager password to decrypt login credentials: ")
                #if c_password == m_password:
                b64_encrypted_password = user_pass[1]
                encrypted_password = base64.b64decode(b64_encrypted_password)
                decrypt_user_pass = k.decrypt(encrypted_password).decode('utf-8')
                print(decrypt_user_pass)
                break
                #else:
                 #   print("Invalid password.")
            break
    else:
        print("Site Account not found.")

searchAndDecrypt('./test.json', cipher)  # prints out 'bar'
```

Try this out on your end. Note that I changed `site` to just a string called `'site'` and commented out the pwinput stuff and added some new parameters.

Comment: Okay, this worked on my end! So do you think it could be something to do with requesting the user input?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure but the error said that you had an invalid token and it wasn't able to decrypt, that to me sounds like the wrong cipher was trying to be used to decrypt so perhaps a new cipher was being created or the original one was being changed in some way?

Comment: I have just edited my question to include how I have generated/saved my cipher. Have I made a mistake in that?

Comment: Can you double check your file? I had something weird happen the first time where the file was empty but the second time it had the key. It seems to work though

Comment: the key file? It has a key in it. As far as I can tell it's not changing as the code is being run

Comment: Yeah when I tried to save the key to key.key, it wound up blank, but reruns were fine. Have you gotten it working though, or are you still getting the same error?